# Параметры (аргументы ) в функции

Tags: javascript

Можете пожалуйста истолковать как эти параметры (аргументы) работаю в функциях ,я перечитал массу литературы , английской и русской , просто не понимаю как это работает , все кажется не сложно , но вот именно эти аргументы вообще в голову не лезут. Вот к примеру я создаю функцию :

```
function  myFunc(a,b) {
console.log(a+b);
}
```

и ничерта не работает , подчеркивает мне мои оба аргумента a и b , пытался сделать так

```
function myFunc("Hello","World")
```

и всеравно подчеркивает эти аргументы и ругается на них , не может определить (is not defined) , прошу помогите кто знает

Comment: Служебное слово `function` нужно при определении функции, при вызове нет.

Answer (score 4):

> вот именно эти аргументы вообще в голову не лезут

Используйте другие :)

```
myFunc("Bye", "Alexander");
```

```js
function myFunc(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

myFunc("Hello", "World");
```

В мое время `а` и `b` в `function myFunc(a, b) { ... }` называли формальными параметрами, а значения, подаваемые в вызов `myFunc("Hello","World")`, - фактическими.

> Our functions don't have parameters, they have arguments, and they always win them!

Comment: спасибо , но как все - таки как работают эти параметры , я их назначию числом либо стрингой и просто например делаю a +b где a это 1 параметр а b 2 или как ? Как он идентефицирует это , как он понимает что я хочу сложить например : function (1,2,3,4)  { a+c   }

Comment: Или я могу только сделать так function (a,c) {a+c} ?

Comment: Вы точно читали литературу по JS?

Comment: Да я читал точно , у меня все гладко идет все понимаю , но вот конкретно эту тему я вообще одуплить не могу(

Comment: Прочитайте отличие параметров функции от аргументов